# Method getAlpha() with type int not found on target class class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to use the example from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA) with code [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ActivityAnimations.zip), about custom animations into a `GridView`.

All is working OK until I try to use a BitmapDrawable instead of a ColorDrawable.

```
mBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.activity_background);
topView.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackground);
```

If using a `BitmapDrawable`, when swiping from main activity to the `PictureDetailsActivity` and back, makes the background from the main activity disappear. In logs I keep seeing this error when the background is gone (sometimes background is gone only when swiping the list, with the same error below):

```
Method getAlpha() with type int not found on target class
class android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

Searching the error I cannot find anything about it.

*EDIT:*
I am using alpha for fading in and out the background, as in the example:

```
// Fade in the background
ObjectAnimator bgAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mBackground, "alpha", 0, 255);
bgAnim.setDuration(duration * 2);
bgAnim.start();
```

and

```
// Fade out background
ObjectAnimator bgAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mBackground, "alpha", 0);
bgAnim.setDuration(duration * 2);
bgAnim.start();
```

Comment: Can you post the lines of code that is using the getAlpha() method?

Comment: What's the SDK version of the target you are testing against? `getAlpha()` is API19

Comment: I have minVersion 14 and targetVersion 19

Comment: :) How about the device/emulator you are testing your app on?

Comment: Anyhow, the background disappearing is probably not related with the error you are seeing. Your app might actually be running out of memory. What are the dimensions of the bitmap?

Comment: I have a small pattern repeating: <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern"
    android:tileMode="repeat">
</bitmap>. It is not the memory, it is the API version, getAlpha() is only from API 19...didn't noticed that...thanks. Will look for alternatives. Can you please post the answer so i can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably testing on a device/emulator which is `< API19`, while [`getAlpha()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#getAlpha%28%29) was only added on API19. Hence,

```
Method getAlpha() with type int not found
```

Please make sure to test on a target with minimum Android 4.4 (KitKat) installed.